# createUserDefinedFunction : if already exists?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using [azure-documentdb java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java) in order to create and use "User Defined Functions (UDFs)"

So from the [official documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#javascript-integration) I finally find the way (with a Java client) on **how to create an UDF**:

```
String regexUdfJson = "{"
          + "id:\"REGEX_MATCH\","
          + "body:\"function (input, pattern) { return input.match(pattern) !== null; }\","
          + "}";
UserDefinedFunction udfREGEX = new UserDefinedFunction(regexUdfJson);
getDC().createUserDefinedFunction(
    myCollection.getSelfLink(),
    udfREGEX,
    new RequestOptions());
```

And here is a sample query :

```
SELECT * FROM root r WHERE udf.REGEX_MATCH(r.name, "mytest_.*")
```

I had to create the UDF one time only because I got an exception if I try to recreate an existing UDF:

```
DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["The input name presented is already taken. Ensure to provide a unique name property for this resource type."]}
```

How should I do to know if the UDF already exists ? 
I try to use "readUserDefinedFunctions" function without success. Any example / other ideas ?

Maybe for the long term, should we suggest a "createOrReplaceUserDefinedFunction(...)" on [azure feedback](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/8284620-add-createorreplaceuserdefinedfunction-feat)

Comment: Dear illuminator @abatishchev why did you update my java code to c# ?

Comment: Sorry about this. Your question was lacking a language tag. I put an incorrect one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for existing UDFs by running query using `queryUserDefinedFunctions`.

Example:

```
List<UserDefinedFunction> udfs = client.queryUserDefinedFunctions(
        myCollection.getSelfLink(),
        new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id=@id",
                         new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter("@id", myUdfId))),
        null).getQueryIterable().toList();
if (udfs.size() > 0) {
    // Found UDF.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer for .NET users.

```
`var collectionAltLink = documentCollections["myCollection"].AltLink; // Target collection's AltLink
var udfLink = $"{collectionAltLink}/udfs/{sampleUdfId}"; // sampleUdfId is your UDF Id
var result = await _client.ReadUserDefinedFunctionAsync(udfLink);
var resource = result.Resource;
if (resource != null)
{
   // The UDF with udfId exists
}`
```

Here `_client` is Azure's `DocumentClient` and `documentCollections` is a dictionary of your documentDb collections.

If there's no such UDF in the mentioned collection, the `_client` throws a *NotFound* exception.